# how to render child component in ember.js v3.8?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember.js-component

Before Im working in v2.15 and i can render child component  by

```
{{component/child-component}}
```

but cannot render child component on v3.8 how can i render child component?

```
<Component />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested components are invoked in angle bracket component invokation syntax using `::` as separator:

```
// Before
{{component/child-component}}

// After
<Component::ChildComponent />
```

You could find more details about this in the corresponding RFC: [Nested Invocations in Angle Bracket Syntax #457](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0457-nested-lookups.md)

The features is not supported before Ember 3.10 natively. But there is a polyfill making it available in Ember >= 2.12: [ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill)